# ListTile covers button animation

Tags: flutter

Just noticed that ListTile cover button animation when wrapped inside a container with background color set to anything but transparent. Wrapping ListTile in a container with set color is the only way I know to change background color of ListTile. Is there any other way to change background color of the ListTile without loosing button animation?

```
           Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Test'),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
            )
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the way **InkWell** works (Some buttons, like the IconButton, use **InkWell** or **InkResponse** as their parent). You can read about it more on [this github issue page](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3782#issuecomment-217566214).

In order to make that ripple effect to display on top of the decorated Container (the green one in your code) - it needs a **Material** widget above the Container in the widget display tree.
So you should edit the code and add a **Material** widget with transparency in your Container, so the widget display tree will look like Container -> Material -> Ink.

```
Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Material(
            type: MaterialType.transparency,
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text('Test'),
              trailing: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Wow thank you... didn't expect such a quick respond... I didn't know that.. I hope this will be somehow fixed or changed so we don't have to wrap widgets to another widget

Comment: If you read the comment on that github page - you will see, that there is actually nothing to be fixed as this is not a bug, but how it should actually work. Inks trigger ripple effect on the closest Material widget available under them.